# String comparison operators

Tags: c++, string

How do they work? I'm so confused. Folks say you can compare string lexicographically, but that isn't the case. Running this program, you see that it works only sometimes.

There is a post on the site that says if it is a string literal it won't work, but even with declared strings, like these in my program, it gives me error messages. What gives? Can I or can't I compare strings with the ">" "<" operators?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void stringCompare(string c, string d){
    if(c < d){
    cout << "It's less than!" <<endl;
    }
    else{
    cout << "It's Greater then!" <<endl;
    }


}

int main(){
    while(true){
    string c,d;
    cout << "Enter First Number "<< endl;
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Enter Second Number" <<endl;
    cin >> d;
    stringCompare(c,d);
    }

}
```

Input output for a few values:

a, B  ->'a' is less than

A, b  -> 'A' is less than

c, D  -> 'c' is greater than

????

Comment: Please define _sometimes_, or this doesn't mean anything. Just provide an example that doesn't work.

Comment: I posted some above. When comparing 'c' and 'D', it says 'c' is greater

Comment: Am I not inputting things correctly into my functions. I need to be able to compare strings lexograpghically, I need to know if it's possible to do this correctly without random errors

Comment: Can't reproduce your input/output examples: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0937117984d25c3 Also you know that all uppercase letters < than lowercase letters in lexicographic ordering in ascii?

Comment: **−1** The example i/o does not correspond to the presented code.

Comment: I know that they were on different spectrums of ASCII but I heard you could still compare in a string like sense. This is the reason for the question. Jeez, what is wrong with you people? Such nit pickers. It's like you come to the question just to be annoying. Thanks to the people that actually came to lend a hand

Comment: the code works fine on my system.Enter First Number
c
Enter Second Number
d
It's less than!
c<d
Enter First Number
a
Enter Second Number
d
It's less than!
a<d
Enter First Number
A
Enter Second Number
b
It's less than!
A<b
Enter First Number

Comment: I want alphebetic, regardless if it's capital or lowercase

Comment: the code is fine with me too....I don't get the same output

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the operator overload for `<` work according to a lexicographical case sensitive comparison.

You are not obtaining a random error, the fact is that `a` != `A`.

To have a case insensitive comparison you should first convert both strings to lowercase, something like:

```
string lowercase;
lowercase.resize(text.size());
transform(text.begin(), text.end(), lowercase.begin(), ::tolower);
```

And then compare them.

Comment: This transforms the entire stirng to lowercase? How about for numbers? Will numbers that are strings compare in the traditional sense all the time?

Comment: Yes, their order will reflect the algebraic one.

Comment: According to original question, he got "c, d -> 'c' is greater than", which can not be explained anyway.

Comment: Additional note: calling `toupper` on raw `char`s can lead to problems. You want to cast to `unsigned char` first.

Comment: I'd like to point it out that with numbers you get correct results assuming there is no leading zeroes, for example check it out here: http://ideone.com/mFlGlQ If you need to compare strings which are numbers is always better to convert them to numerical values before.

Comment: `a != A` Ayn Rand does not approve of this assertion.